# CSS HTML How to get rid of the button border

Tags: html, css

I want to make a clean and awesome website but the only problem is I don't know how to get rid of the button border please help will be greatly appreciated

if you want to have a look at my problem go to thi
https://i.stack.imgur.com/daaec.jpg
I don't want to see any button border or image border

If you want to have a look at my code please go to http://pastebin.com/b0Mp68Jm
Kind Regards 
CreepyC

Comment: Have you tried: border: none; in your button and image css?

Comment: try border:none to image and button or parent of it.

Comment: `button { border: 0px; }`

Comment: "*want to make a clean and awesome website but **the only problem is** I don't know how to get rid of the button border*" - that's hilarious ;-)

Comment: the img tag are not closed

Comment: Btw. you don't have to use buttons either, usually you rather want anchors (*<a ...></a>*). Buttons are for *forms* but it appears like you want to have navigation. Use anchors for that.

Comment: thomasjaworski.com thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use `border:0;`, the `border:none` also works well, provided you mind you close the `<img>` that you had kept open. Check out the corrected code:

```
<html>


<head>
  <title>Forsaken </title>
  <link href="main.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

   <body>
   <button class="topLeft clear-border"><a href="teams"><img src="icon1.jpg"></a></button>
   <button class="topRight clear-border"><a href="store"><img src="icon1.jpg"></a></button>
   <button class="bottomLeft clear-border"><a href="sponsors"><img src="icon1.jpg"></a></button>
   <button class="bottomRight clear-border"><a href="aboutus"><img src="icon1.jpg"></a></button>

</body>


</html>


**CSS**

.topLeft{
  position: absolute;
  top:1;
  left:1;
}
.topRight{
  position: absolute;
  top:1;
  right: 1;
}

.bottomleft{
position: fixed;
left: 1px;
}

.bottomright{
position: fixed;
right: 1px;
}

.clear-border{
  border:0;
}
```